# Import leaflet Draw into an angular 2 project

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am new to Angular2.  Built with Cli.  Although I was able to get Leaflet imported into this Angular2 project without any Angular2 directives.  I would like to do the same with Leaflet Draw extension.  I haven't been able to get Draw to work. Basically, I wanna import a module that extends another on the same namespace.  Leaflet in this case.  Doesn't anyone know how to do that?

Here is my package.json

```
{
"name": "amscm-web",
  "version": "2.0.31c",
  "license": "",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project src/tsconfig.json --type-check && tslint \"e2e/**/*.ts\" --project e2e/tsconfig.json --type-check",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.3",
    "@asymmetrik/angular2-leaflet": "^2.1.5",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.26",
    "@qontu/ngx-inline-editor": "^0.2.0-alpha.4",
    "@types/leaflet-draw": "^0.4.5",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^1.0.20",
    "angular-sortablejs": "^2.0.6",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "leaflet": "^1.0.3",
    "leaflet-draw": "^0.4.9",
    "ng-select": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "ng2-dnd": "^4.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "sortablejs": "^1.6.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.3",
    "@types/gapi": "0.0.33",
    "@types/gapi.auth2": "0.0.39",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.0.63",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.1",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.4.3",
    "typescript": "latest",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.0"
  }
}
```

also here is my map.model.ts

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.draw'

export class LeafletMapModel {

  constructor(
    public baseLayers: {
      id: string,
      name: string,
      enabled: boolean,
      layer: L.Layer
    }[],
    public baseLayer: string,
    public overlayLayers: {
      id: string,
      name: string,
      enabled: boolean,
      layer: L.Layer
    }[] = []
  ) { }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Leaflet } from 'leaflet';
import { Draw } from 'leaflet-draw';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  _layer = Leaflet.layer;
  _draw = Draw.drawLocal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet.  I just tried this in my component.  I get the compile error **'File C:/projects/myProject/index.d.ts' is not a module.** any idea why I am getting this compile error.

Comment: Looks like Leaflet is a JS lib, so Typescript cannot use it as-is, it needs type declaration. Look at the example [here](https://haoliangyu.github.io/2016/05/06/Making-A-Map-with-Leaflet-in-TypeScript/) on how to import the types an use Leaflet after.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach worked for me pretty well:

```
npm install leaflet@latest --save
```

and in the Angular component:

```
       import * as L from 'leaflet';
...
        @ViewChild('map') mapElement;
          ngOnInit() {
    const myMap = this.mapElement.nativeElement;
    const map = L.map(myMap).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
        .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
        .openPopup();

}
```